# double printing in pycharm

Tags: python, recursion, pycharm

I'm writing some recursive functions as part of my homework.

I wrote this piece of code for printing all binary sequences of length n:

```
def binary_sequences_helper(n, sequence):
    if len(sequence) == n:
        print(sequence)
    else:
        binary_sequences_helper(n, sequence + '0')
        binary_sequences_helper(n, sequence + '1')


def print_binary_sequences(n):
    binary_sequences_helper(n, '')


print_binary_sequences(1)
```

The output in the pycharm shell is

```
0
1
0
1
```

Instead of just 0 1 when I run exactly the same code in the IDLE or on my friend's computer.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: the output is consistently `0 1 0 1`? What if you pass `flush=True` to the print function?

Comment: Something's must be messed up in your environment, on my pycharm it looks fine (no double printing).

Comment: i suspect this code does not actually do what you are hoping it does regardless of the IDE that you are running it in ... I have a hard time seeing a problem statement that this code could answer correctly

Comment: the output is consistently doubled than what it should be

Comment: Works for me too. I doubt it'll help but - try clearing your cache (File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart)

Comment: it helped restarting my Cache.

Comment: I'll add that as the answer then. Feel free to mark it as resolved when you're able :)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42350488/2451431) post helped me understand the problem a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code.

As per the comments a few people (myself included) tried running it and it worked as you expected.

Therefore, I suspect it's a problem with your PyCharm. Try clearing the cache by doing to `File` -> `Invalidate and Restart`.

Comment: When you do this, there are 4 options: "Invalidate and Restart", "Invalidate", "Cancel", and "Just Restart". For somebody coming across this also seeing double-printing in PyCharm, which button should they click?