# Method executed twice in python

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the following class with a static method:

```
class Helper:
     @staticmethod
    def LookForCuiInLocal(disease, language):
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(stuff here)

        cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)

        findLocalQuery = ("SELECT umls_concept_id from translation WHERE source_text = '{}'".format(disease))
        print("hey")

        try:
            cursor.execute(findLocalQuery)
            resultList = cursor.fetchone()[0]
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
            return resultList
        except (mysql.connector.Error, TypeError) as e:
            print("Error when finding local CUI : {}".format(e))
            return None

print(Helper().LookForCuiInLocal("paradentose", "da"))
```

I have a database where i run the query and it might return a string i need. If it doesn't contain the string the method fails and returns None.

I get the following output:

```
hey
c0031099
hey
c0031099
```

Why is the method executed twice?
I hope someone can help me with this.

EDIT:
I'm using PyCharm as my IDE

EDIT2: Changing to the following does not help the issue:

```
def LookForCuiInLocal(disease, language):
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(stuff here)

    cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)

     findLocalQuery = ("SELECT umls_concept_id from translation WHERE source_text = '{}'".format(disease))
     print("hey")

      try:
          cursor.execute(findLocalQuery)
          resultList = cursor.fetchone()[0]
          cursor.close()
          conn.close()
          return resultList
    except (mysql.connector.Error, TypeError) as e:
          print("Error when finding local CUI : {}".format(e))
          return None

print(Helper().LookForCuiInLocal("paradentose", "da"))
```

However, calling LookForCuiInLocal() from another script does not make the method run twice

Comment: How do you call the script? What's the environment? Edit the question.

Comment: I don't think that code would reproduce the problem you are describing.

Comment: What is the minimal example that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: This doesn't address the problem, but your last line has an extraneous set of parens. It would be better as `print(Helper.LookForCuiInLocal("paradentose", "da"))`

Comment: Is `LookForCuiInLocal` the only method/property in that class?

Comment: @PeterWood I'm using pycharm, and just calling the script in that.

Comment: @JCVanHamme Noted. Thanks.

Comment: @Elmex80s No. There are other methods in the class, but they do something else independently of that method

Comment: @ChristianA if the other methods in your class are static as well you might want to consider wrapping them in a module instead of a class.

Comment: @kazemakase removing everything but the print("hey") still gives me two runs of the method.

Comment: @Elmex80s Yeah okay. I will look into that. Thanks

Comment: How do you run the script in PyCharm?

Comment: are you running the file as the main module and also importing it? Do all commands in the global scope run twice, try adding `print("running",__name__)` to the file.

Comment: Do you have an `__init__` for `Helper` that might be calling the `LookForCuiInLocal` function?

Comment: @PeterWood I right click the script, and press run

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen 
The function only runs twice if I call it inside the script. If I import the module, and call the function it runs one time

Comment: @JCVanHamme I don't have an __init__ function.

Comment: ok If you put just a print statement in the main body of the module does it get run twice? What if you put the call inside the condition `if __name__ == "__main__":` does it only run once?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Using if __name__ == "__main__" seems to have done the trick. Weird. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have the file `foo.py` containing this code

```
print("running from", __name__)
import foo
```

When you run the file (it is the *main* entry point for the program) it is run under the name `__main__`, when it is imported it runs the file **a second time** under the name `foo`, so the output would be

```
running from __main__
running from foo
```

Rarely do you have a file import itself, usually this happens with circular imports - when `foo` will import `bar` which will import `foo`.

For the module to have code that should be importable and code that should only be run when it is the main program, put the main-only code inside the condition:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

This will cause it to only run when the module is the entry point and **not when it is imported.**

Comment: Well. If I only run the module and print a function like: print(UMLS_Helper().LookForCuiInLocal("hepatitis c", "da"))

It will run twice. It might be cause of the imports. I import another module, which eventually imports my main controller. I don't know if that is what is causing the issue.

Putting the print("running from", __name__) only nets me 

running from __main__
c0019196

Which shows it's only running once